# Как создать свое приложение, используя laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

На старте создания небольшого приложения(далее - my application) столкнулся с трудностью организации папок в laravel. Буду благодарен, если вы поможете разобраться в следующих вопросах:

1) Я решил вынести my application в отдельную папку. Это лучше сделать в корневой папке сайта или в папке vendor?

2) Хочу, чтобы у my application был свой route, как к нему правильно строить маршрутизацию? Мой колхозный вариант: создаем route в папке my application, прописываем там необходимые роуты, далее делаем рекваер в routes/web.php, при этом route обращается к папке App\Http\Controllers, из-за чего приходится переписывать пути.

3) Если я вынес приложение в отдельную папку, получается, что все связанные с ним файлы, включая views, css, js, cache и т.д должны находится в этой папке?

p.s Прошу не закидывать за второй пункт, а объяснить правильный подход.

Comment: у тебя тут много вопросов и тут на них ответ в томах будет.
Оставлю ссылку на ютуб учителя с него я начал понимать структуру. 
находи у него урок ларавель 1 и смотри. штук 15 сядь посмотри за раз и потом все уловишь
https://www.youtube.com/user/simpletrainingcom/videos

Comment: Если были навыки програмирования то все быстро поймешь и сможешь уже писать свою идею. Удачи

Comment: Читать документацию и посмотреть best practice